# hide some middle part of URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to change URL like following

```
http://www.xyz.com/dfur/admin/public/index/qwerty
```

to

```
http://www.xyz.com/dfur/admin/qwerty
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Which is the URL you would like to type in, and which is where files are located? Have you tried anything yet, and if so what? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Do you want an external redirect (the client will see the second url) or do you want an internal rewrite (the client will see the first url)?

Comment: You are looking at apache rewrite. i.e. redirect traffic from .../qwerty to /public/index/qwerty. google for rewrite for some example.

Comment: I am usin Yii(PHP framework)
and in that public is Controller name and index is action
I want to hide controller&action in url only for url which contains public controller

Comment: @samuria8 Client will see 2nd Url

Answer (score 2):

In the root folder (www.xyz.com, usually a folder called `www` or `public_html`) add (or edit) the `.htaccess` file with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dfur/admin/public/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^dfur/admin/(.*)$ /dfur/admin/public/index/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That is doing reverse. As per OP `Client will see 2nd Url`

Comment: Eh, oops. Let me fix that.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check if this is better

Answer (score -1):

The following rewriterule will redirect the client with an external redirect from any url that begins with `dfur/admin/public/index/` to an url that begins with `dfur/admin/`. `([^/]*)` in the first argument of RewriteRule will make a capturing group we can use in the second argument (`$1`). If all rewriterules work as expected, change `R` (the redirect flag) to `R=301` to make it a permanent redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^dfur/admin/public/index/(.*)$ dfur/admin/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I don't want redirect I just want "public/index" get hides from the url

Comment: And... how do you expect to accomplish that without a redirect? I am not familiar with `mod_sorcery`...